# My DLL in listed in GAC does not appear in VS when trying to reference it

Tags: windows, visual-studio, gac, gacutil

Ive copied my DLL to the GAC and ive verified it is in the GAC by listing all assemblies with

```
gacutil -l
```

Still i cant reference to it in Visual Studio since it wont be listed. Is there some kind of refresh i need to do? Ive tried reinstalling and restarting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Add Reference" dialog in Visual Studio is independent of the GAC as it is controlled by the **AssemblyFolders** registry key. Hence, if your assembly doesn't appear in the "Add Reference" dialog then you are missing a corresponding registry key. Please see a detailed guidance from Microsoft about how to add a registry key to list an assembly in Visual Studio for direct referencing [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/306149/how-to-display-an-assembly-in-the-add-reference-dialog-box).